# What real platforms map hardware ports to memory addresses?

Tags: c++, c, memory, ports, memory-mapping

I sometimes see statements that on some platforms the following C or C++ code:

```
int* ptr;
*ptr = 0;
```

can result in writing to a hardware input-output port if `ptr` happens to store the address to which that port is mapped. Usually they are called "embedded platforms".

What are real examples of such platforms?

Comment: Just to add to all the answers, your x86 platform also does this (Memory Mapped I/O). You are just used to work in a protected environment[1] created by your OS, so you don't have to (or by accident can) touch all the dirty aspects of real hardware. Write a driver, or better yet, an OS and you will have to deal with Memory Mapped I/O a lot, among a whole host of other fun things. :) [1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_mode

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371953/memory-mapped-i-o-vs-port-mapped-i-o

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most systems in my experience use memory-mapped I/O.  The x86 platform has a separate, non-memory-mapped I/O address space (that uses the `in`/`out` family of processor op-codes), but the PC architecture also extensively uses the standard memory address space for device I/O, which has a larger address space, faster access (generally), and easier programming (generally).

I think that the separate I/O address space was used initially because the memory address space of processors was sometimes quite limited and it made little sense to use a portion of it for device access.  Once the memory address space was opened up to megabytes or more, that reason to separate I/O addresses from memory addresses became less important.

I'm not sure how many processors provide a separate I/O address space like the x86 does. As an indication of how the separate I/O address space has fallen out of favor, when the x86 architecture moved into the 32-bit realm, nothing was done to increase the I/O address space from 64KB (though they did add the ability to move 32-bit chunks of data in one instruction).  When x86 moved into the 64-realm, the I/O address space remained at 64KB and they didn't even add the ability to move data in 64-bit units...

Also note that modern desktop and server platforms (or other systems that use virtual memory) generally don't permit an application to access I/O ports, whether they're memory-mapped or not.  That access is restricted to device drivers, and even device drivers will have some OS interface to deal with virtual memory mappings of the physical address and/or to set up DMA access.

On smaller systems, like embedded systems, I/O addresses are often accessed directly by the application. For systems that use memory-mapped addresses, that will usually be done by simply setting a pointer with the physical address of the device's I/O port and using that pointer like any other. However, to ensure that the access occurs and occurs in the right order, the pointer must be declared as pointing to a `volatile` object.

To access a device that uses something other than a memory-mapped I/O port (like the x86's I/O address space), a compiler will generally provide an extension that allows you to read or write to that address space.  In the absence of such an extension, you'd need to call an assembly language function to perform the I/O.

Comment: I have been doing research on this topic lately, and your answer proved to be extremely useful. I have a couple of questions : what devices use the i/o address space ? And, since the memory will be common for memory mapped devices and all programs (in memory mapped i/o), what would happen when the memory mapped space is being used ? Is that space rendered unavailable for that time ?

Comment: Some examples of devices that use the I/O address space on PCs are things like the PS/2 keyboard, legacy COM ports. I'm sure there are quire a few other things. I'm not a hardware designer, so I don't know if new device designed would use the I/O space or prefer the memory-mapped space even if the the number of ports involved was small (it seems to me that nearly everything except video adapters plugs into USB, or SATA nowadays).

Comment: As for application access to memory mapped I/O, in systems that support virtual addresses that memory would typically not be mapped in the process space except maybe by some specific request that allows the system to still arbitrate between applications.

Comment: Using of separate instructions for I/O on the 8080 meant that if an RST vector accidentally pointed at an RST instruction it may trash all of memory but wouldn't hit random I/O devices.  The 8088 was largely an offshoot of the 8080, and likely followed in its footsteps for similar reasons, even though the stack pointer on the 8088 wouldn't reach outside a 64K segment.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, Why do you say that most systems use memory-mapped I/O when most Intel microprocessors use port-mapped? (Intel x86 and compatible processors all use port-mapped.)

Comment: @Pacerier: What part do you consider controversial?  The 8080 and 8088 documentation describe the behaviors in question.  As for "most systems", microcontrollers far outnumber desktop PCs, and anything based on any PIC, 68HCxx family, or ARM will use memory-mapped I/O.  Some other controllers including the 8x51 perform I/O using fixed-address instructions, but they're vastly outnumbered by even the three families mentioned.

Comment: @Pacerier: For example, the "Linux Device Driver, 3rd Ed" book by Rubini & Corbet says, "It's interesting to note that no processor outside the x86 family features a different address space for ports".

Comment: And even in the Intel x86 world (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)): "Memory-mapped I/O is preferred in x86-based architectures because the instructions that perform port-based I/O are limited to one register ... memory-mapped I/O uses fewer instructions and can run faster than port I/O. AMD did not extend the port I/O instructions when defining the x86-64 architecture to support 64-bit ports, so 64-bit transfers cannot be performed using port I/O."

Comment: @MichaelBurr: If one focuses only on current-manufacture reprogrammable microcomputers the x86 may be alone in its use of separate I/O space, but it's only unique in that regard if one ignores other historical processors as well as old and new embedded controllers and DSPs.

Comment: Perhaps we should keep in mind that I only said, "Most systems **in my experience** use memory-mapped I/O". Also, I think - it's been more than 5 years - that I was really trying to say that that most *architectures* rather than most installed processors use memory-mapped I/O (though again, I'm going mainly by personal experience rather than statistic that can be backed by a firm citation).  If anyone likes, I can change the wording to "Many architectures..." instead of "Most systems....".

Answer (score 2):

This is called Memory-mapped I/O, and a good place to start is the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_io).

Modern operating systems usually protect you from this unless you're writing drivers, but this technique is relevant even on PC architectures. Remember the DOS 640Kb limit? That's because memory addresses from 640K to 1Mb were allocated for I/O.

Answer (score 1):

PlayStation. That was how we got some direct optimized access to low-level graphics (and other) features of the system.

Answer (score 1):

[An NDIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549338%28VS.85%29.aspx) driver on Windows is an example. This is called memory mapped I/O and the benefit of this is performance.

Answer (score 1):

See [Embedded-Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) for examples of devices that use  Memory-mapped I/O e.g. routers,adsl-modems,  microcontroller etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly used when writing drivers, since most peripheral devices communicate with the main CPU through memory mapped registers.

Answer (score 0):

Motorola 68k series and PowerPC are the big ones.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this in modern Windows (and I'm pretty sure Linux offers it too). It's called memory mapped files. You can load a file into memory on Windows and then write/alter it just by manipulating pointers.

Comment: I do not think this is what the OP is talking about. Memory Mapped I/O is different from Memory Mapped files.