# Memory mapped I/O vs Port mapped I/O

Tags: memory, assembly, architecture, io, cpu

Memory mapped I/O is a technique which allows the use of central memory (RAM) to communicate with peripherals. Port mapped I/O uses ports (with special assembly instructions) to communicate over digital ports.

What are the advantages of one method with respect to another?

Comment: Best to read the FAQ before posting - http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: The advantage of Memory mapped IO would be that you don't need special instructions to write to devices. It would look like a memory write, but certain addresses would map to certain sets of devices. Port-mapped I/O uses a different class of instructions.

Comment: Having a separate I/O bus is pretty specific to Intel processors.  This dates back to their early days of 8-bit processors.  Where bus designs were exceedingly simple and having to pick a hole in the 64KB address space was hard.  These considerations just don't apply anymore today.

Comment: Can you actually *choose* between one or the other for a given device / on a given architecture? (When writing drivers or so.) Because if not this is a hardware design / computer engineering question, not a programming one.

Comment: some pci peripherals would allow you to use I/O or memory mapped access, I assume so that the boards can work on non-intel machines (which there used to be more of) the I/O space support is mostly gone. it is something the peripheral has to be designed to support, it is not a software or processor thing.

Comment: you could also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333849/what-real-platforms-map-hardware-ports-to-memory-addresses?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Cthulhu said,

- memory mapped I/O allows writing/reading to I/O device ports the same as reading/writing to normal memory (using the same machine code/asm)

but there is a disadvantage:

- you use up physical memory address space for your memory mapped I/O devices (think of 32 bit Windows not being able to access all 4G of RAM on a PC)

So an advantage of using the port mapped I/O method is that you have a separate address space for your I/O devices and you can use the whole memory addressing range to access memory.

EDIT: Here is a more complete answer to your question: [hardware ports to memory addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333849/what-real-platforms-map-hardware-ports-to-memory-addresses?rq=1)

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/703695/78897